# Merge rows by "Key" column for a large data table in R (more than 30 million rows)

Tags: r, list, merge, data.table

I'm trying to merge rows of two data tables A and B based on a common column "key" but R is not able to handle merging such a large data table. It's of around 30 million rows
Is there any way I can merge those either in data table or by converting into lists?

#### Edit:

I tried

```
merge(dt1,dt2, by ="key", all.x = TRUE)
```

I got an error saying

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 802 Mb

Here is an example of what my data looks like

Data Table 1

```
 key ||   age || ctg || total_spend
==================================
key1 ||    45 ||   1 ||    1026
key2 ||    26 ||   2 ||    1574
key3 ||    45 ||   1 ||    64
key4 ||    32 ||   1 ||    1610
key5 ||    41 ||   1 ||    884
```

Data Table 2

```
key  ||   age || ctg || total_income (lacs)
==========================================
key1 ||    45 ||   1 ||    7.5
key2 ||    26 ||   2 ||    6
key3 ||    45 ||   1 ||    4
key5 ||    41 ||   1 ||    5.3
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result of these trials?

Comment: I didnt get the result. I tried merge(dt1,dt2, by ="key", all.x = TRUE)..
I got and error saying "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 802 Mb"

Comment: How much RAM has your computer available? Are you using the `data.table` package? There are [benchmarks](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping) with up to 2 billion = 200 crore rows. (Sufficiently sized hardware required.)

Comment: You might consider an alternative to storing the data in memory, such as a SQL type database. For large datasets I have had good success using the MonetdbLite package (see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite-R )

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and give a [mcve] *including* the expected output for your sample (which hopefully is representative for your full dataset.) - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given sufficient RAM, the `data.table` package should be capable of merging the two tables:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt1, key = "key")
setDT(dt2, key = "key")
dt1[dt2]
```

Comment: thank u.. but this does not help. The row numbers are different in both the tables. So it throws an error.. And yet again when i choose EACHi = TRUE, it gives the memory allocation error. I have already made provisions for memory, but the data is huge and hence this doesn't  work out for me

Comment: @zd06 What is the exact error message, please? And, `EACHi = TRUE` seems no valid `data.table` syntax to me.

Comment: @Ralf The code u suggested worked after I removed unnecessary data from the environment. I guess that was the memory allocation problem